# В чём разница между парсером и лексером?

Tags: лексер, парсер

Если я описал синтаксис языка программирования с помощью yacc-подобной утилиты,
то это парсер или лексер?

Как строго определяются эти термины?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Разница между этими понятиями очень точная. Лексер распознает лексемы (токены). Например, если мы анализируем запись какого-то выражения, то отдельными токенами будут числа и знаки операций. На этом работа лексера заканчивается. Парсер же на основе списка токенов выполняет синтаксический анализ и далее уже строит какую-то модель на основании токенов, например, может построить дерево вычисления выражения.

Comment: Окей, тогда tokenizer -- это точно тоже самое что и lexer?

Comment: Это почти одно и то же. Но обычно tokenizer просто разбивает поток на фрагменты строк и на этом работа заканчивается. А lexer помечает эти обравки строк типами (строка, число, оператор и т.п.). В этом смысле, lexer немного более продвинутая штука.